# Java functions argument not change

Tags: java, algorithm

I have some code. In main function i push six element in BST. when i look to debugger, i see that variable  size = 5, but variable root = null. Why variable root not change.

```
package Search;

public class BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Val> {
private class Node{
    Key key;
    Val val;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node prev;
    Node(Key k, Val v){
        key = k;
        val = v;
    }
}
public void push(Key k, Val v){
    push(root,k,v);
}
private void push(Node x, Key k, Val v){
    if(x == null){
        x = new Node(k,v);
        size++;
        return;
    }
    int cmp = x.key.compareTo(k);
    if(cmp > 0)
        push(x.left,k,v);
    else if(cmp < 0)
        push(x.right,k,v);
    else
        x.val = v;

}
Node root = null;
int size = 0;
public static void main(String args[]){
    BST<String,Integer> bst = new BST<String, Integer>();
    bst.push("c",1);
    bst.push("b",2);
    bst.push("d",3);
    bst.push("a",4);
    bst.push("e",5);
    bst.push("c",6);
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `if` block, the assignment:

```
x = new Node(k,v);
```

doesn't make your `root` reference point to the new `Node` object. It's just the local `x` reference of that method which is assigned to `new Node()`. It won't affect `root`, which will be `null` only. This is because, Java passes the references by value. Once you change the reference value of `x` by assigning it to a new object, it will not be the same as `root` anymore.

Just remove that `if` block from the 2nd `push()` method. You should rather do that task in the first `push()` method only, where you initialize the `root` itself before passing it to the 2nd `push()` method:

```
public void push(Key k, Val v){
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(k, v);
        size++;
        return;
    }
    push(root,k,v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing `root` by value in `push(Key k, Val v)`. So the assignment to x doesnt assign the field `root`.